# Как можно ввести три команды в CMD друг за другом?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd

Как можно ввести три команды друг за другом, чтобы не открывалась CMD, вводилась команда, закрывалась и открывалась следущяя CMD, в которую вводилась вторая команда, а чтобы все три команды вводились в один CMD.

Мне надо, чтобы вводилась команда `cd /`, после нее `cd C:\Sherik`, а после нее команда `"pyinstaller -F -w " + name + ".py"`.

Comment: Разве это такая проблема?29 человек посмотрели не один человек не ответил правильно

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой (__«почему этот код не работает?»__) должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения __прямо в вопросе__. Вопросы без __явного описания проблемы__ бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Kiber_kotleta а ты наглый. Если не проблема, то почему сам не сделаешь, как надо?

Comment: @Эникейщик Я разве сказал что легко могу решить свой вопрос но мне лень? я так и ничего не нашел как можно было бы выполнить 3 строки в одну cmd и при этом чтоб все команды выполнялись полностю, я бы и сам это сделал бы если бы знал как

Comment: А разве это такая проблема? Должно быть легко найти, не?

Comment: Да это проблема, при поиске в интернете ничего подобного я не нашел

Comment: Т.е. вам известно, что "это проблема", однако в первом комментарии вы обвиняете всех, что никто не ответил правильно? Или как вообще тот комментарий понимать? Тут вам вообще никто ничего не должен, если что.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Для Windows CMD - можно использовать `&` как разделитель комманд:

```
cd /d C:\Sherik & "pyinstaller -F -w ..."
```

Если нужно проверять, чтобы следующая команда запускалась только в том случае, если предыдущая команда отработала **успешно** - используйте `&&`:

```
cd /d C:\Sherik && "pyinstaller -F -w ..."
```

Comment: это не работает, пишет ошибка синтаксиса перед C:/Sherik

Comment: с воем ответе я показал как запускать несколько команд последовательно в Windows. Разумеется в Python скрипте нужно позаботиться о правильных путях, т.к. обратный слеш используется для указания спец-символов

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй так написать в Python:

```
import os
os.system("cd / & cd C:\\Sherik & \"pyinstaller -F -w \" + name + \".py\"")
```

Comment: проблема в том что после третей команды cmd закрываеться не дожидаясь ответа и команда pyinstaller не успивает выполниться